# Why are two different CMYK colors printed equally?

Tags: print-design, cmyk, color-spaces

With Inkscape, I drew two rectangles, one with CYMK `20/100/0/0` and the other with `2/56/0/43`. Since those two colors are different in the CMYK color space, I expected them to print in different colors. Yet, a (at least my) printer prints both rectangles in the same color (at least in my eye). So, why is my assumption wrong?

Comment: Printer as in the color printer sitting on your desk? Sounds like a calibration problem.

Comment: Yes, a laser printer.

Comment: If a "mauve" (2/56/0/43) looks the same as 20% Cyan -- you've got hardware issues. They should not even be remotely close. Even a horribly calibrated system should not print them the same. Or you are color blind in some way.

Comment: @Scott it's 20% Cyan 100% Magenta, but even then, it's a bright pink vs. a muddy mauve pink. They should not look the same.

Comment: oop... I missed the 100M :) Sorry. In that case calibration *could* be an issue. But I think Lauren is right.. it would need to be some severely off calibration still.